# Importar datos Laravel Excel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-excel

Estoy creando un pequeño sistema el cual tiene una funcion de importar un archivo de laravel.
He podido lograr lo primero sin problema ahora lo que deseo es obtener el id mediante el número de empleado que viene en una columna del excel  pero no he logrado hacerlo ya que cuando consulto la información del usuario para obtener sus datos y poder obtener los registros, la función que recorre el excel deja de funcionar.
Adjunto mi controlador:

```
public function importarIncidencias(Request $request)
{
    $date = new \DateTime();
    $date->format('Y-m-d');
    $quincenaActual=Quincena::where('fecha_inicio', '<=',$date)->where('fecha_limite','>=',$date)->first(); 
    $id_quincenaActual=$quincenaActual->id;

    Excel::load($request->excel, function($reader) use ($id_quincenaActual) {
        $excel = $reader->get();
        // iteracción   
        $reader->each(function($row) use ($id_quincenaActual) {
           $usuario=User::where('no_empleado', '=',$row->no_empleado)->first();              
            $incidencia=new Incidencia();
            $incidencia->fecha=$row->fecha;
            $incidencia->observacion=$row->observacion;
            $incidencia->tipo_incidencia=$row->tipo_incidencia;
            **$incidencia->id_usuario=$usuario->id;**
            $incidencia->id_quincena=$id_quincenaActual;
            $incidencia->save();        

        });

    });
    return back()->with('notificacion', 'Asistencias registradas correctamente');
}
```

El problema se presenta cuando pongo esta linea:

```
$usuario=User::where('no_empleado', '=',$row->no_empleado)->first();
```

También quisiera poder contar las filas que se leyeron, pero al ingresar una variable dentro de la función que recorre el excel mi contador no aumenta.

Gracias

Answer (score 2):

Suponiendo que usas laravel >= 5.7 y tu Facade de Excel sea el de Maatwebsite\Excel.
Para saber las iteraciones, te vale con un simple contador, el resto del código esta bien, aunque te lo puse de una manera mas correcta y organizada (PSR-4)

```
public function importarIncidencias(Request $request)
    {

        $quincenaActual    = Quincena::whereDate('fecha_inicio', '<=', now())->whereDate('fecha_limite', '>=',
            now())->first();

        try {

            DB::beginTransaction();


            Excel::load($request->excel, function ($reader) use ($quincenaActual) {
                $contador = 0;

                // iteracción
                $reader->each(function ($row) use ($quincenaActual, $contador) {

                    $usuario                     = User::where('no_empleado',  $row->no_empleado)->first();

                    $incidencia                  = new Incidencia();
                    $incidencia->fecha           = $row->fecha;
                    $incidencia->observacion     = $row->observacion;
                    $incidencia->tipo_incidencia = $row->tipo_incidencia;
                    $incidencia->id_usuario      = $usuario->id;
                    $incidencia->id_quincena     = $quincenaActual->id;
                    $incidencia->save();

                });

                echo "Iteraciones: " . ++$contador;

            });

        } catch (\Exception $e) {

            DB::rollBack();
            // Aqui se da un error generico que debes controlar
            dd($e);

        }

        return back()->with('notificacion', 'Asistencias registradas correctamente');
    }
```